# Why is $Q^\frac{1}{2}$ a symmetric nonnegative definite?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Im new in Studying stochastic and currently reading to gain something. This question is utilized in The following link

[If $Q$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $U$, $(e_n)$ is an ONB of $U$ consisting of eigenvectors of $Q$, then $(Q^{1/2}e_n)$ is an ONB of $Q^{1/2}U$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659974/if-q-is-an-operator-on-a-hilbert-space-u-e-n-is-an-onb-of-u-consistin?rq=1)

Suppose $Q$ is a bounded, linear, symmetric nonnegative definite trace class operator on a separable Hilbert space $U$.

Due to lack of knowledge I fail to show **why is $Q^\frac{1}{2}$ a symmetric nonnegative definite?** Any help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Every symmetric non-negative definite operator $Q$ has a  unique symmetric non-negative definite square root and the notation for this square root is $Q^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much..